# How to test how many times a component was rendered in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a scenario with 2 components:

- App
- People

I want to test if People gets rendered 10 times inside App. So, I'm trying to test that using Jest. So far, I did this on my **src/App.test.js**:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import People from "./components/People";
import App from './App';

test('Total people = 10', () => {
    expect(App).find(People).toHaveLength(10);
});
```

But I get a message saying:

TypeError: expect(...).find is not a function.

How can I test how many times a component gets rendered inside another component using React and Jest? Can anyone help me?

Comment: you need to render your component first https://reactjs.org/docs/testing-recipes.html#rendering

Comment: Thanks but I didn't understand that very well. I'm very new to React and unit testing. Can you please give another example?

Comment: ok, although it's pretty basic I'll an answer using enzyme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For testing react components first you need to render them, there are some tools for doing that, but since your reasoning in this test is to check how many times a component has been rendered inside another component, [enzyme](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/) does a good job with its shallow method.

```js
import React from "react";
import App from "./App";
import People from "./components/People";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";

it("Total people = 10", () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<App />);
  expect(wrapper.find(People)).toHaveLength(10);
});
```

You'll need to set up enzyme in your project first, read the docs for more details.

The current trend in testing is to check for the things the user actually sees in the page, so most people is using [react-testing-library](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro), It'll be good for you to check it out

Comment: I made some changes on my code following your example. The test and shallow method seem to work fine. Now the problem is that the People component is not being found by any means. I tested other component, and my test count it normally. 

People component is inside a map function, I loop over the results of an API call and return the component 10 times. So why the test shows 0 ocurrences for the People component?

Comment: did you mock the api call? https://dev.to/zaklaughton/the-only-3-steps-you-need-to-mock-an-api-call-in-jest-39mb

Comment: No.. I didn't know I have to do that, never used this before. I think I undestood the part of make a fake axios request, but I didn't get how to put all together. I think I have to study a lot about React testing, there's a lot to learn.

Comment: @churros if my answer helped you with your initial concern please accept it

Answer (score 1):

If you ever switch to [react-testing-library](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro/), you might write the test something like this:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import App from './App';
import {render} from "@testing-library/react";


test('Total people = 10', async () => {
    const { getAllByText } = await render(<App />);

    expect(getAllByText('string_in_People')).toHaveLength(10);
});
```

Basically you'd use one of the library's built-in `getAllBy...` [query methods](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about/) to query for all instances of an element that appears exactly once in each instance of your `<People />` component. The resulting set's length will equal the number of `<People />` instances on the page.